# How to recurse a function itself?

Tags: php

For ex. If I have a function rand(0,2). How do i build a function such that

resc(100,rand(0,2));

Prints the value of rand(0,2) 100 times? For that matter. Any function that is printable.

I tried this.But doesnt seem to work.

```
<?php
function resc($i, $f) {
    if ($i != 0) {
        print $f;
        return resc($i-1, $f);
    } else { 
        print $f;
    }
}
resc(4, rand(0, 1));
?>
```

Comment: Do you need recursion?  What about a loop?

Comment: you just miss a loop in your function.

Comment: @DrixsonOseña Recursion is an implicit loop with a stop condition. You technically don't need an explicit loop like a while or for loops.

Comment: Not really. Writing a loop again and again is painstaking.That is why I was wondering if i can make a function which takes its arguemnts as functions.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep You can write a function that takes another function as callback. The function doesn't have to be recursive for that to work. Generally, onnly use recursion if you really need to. It's a memory hog in most languages, PHP included.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep If you're using 5.3 you can use anonymous functions. It's not quite the same, but that's how you pass functions into arguments. Agreed with kba on avoiding recursion if you can. PHP is interpreted and function calls still go on the call stack. You're eating up enough memory using a language like PHP as is, so don't over do it, unless you're in college of course where they want everything to be recursive ;)

Comment: Ah well.. It seems to work.Thanks for you help anyway.

Comment: @kba But recursion is basically used in almost all functions right? Like array search etc etc. Even a loop is a recursion.

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep there's a difference between looping and iterating. one repeats until the stack is old and busted, the other increments a counter for a given value (foreach and for are iterators, while() is a loop, and recursion is something you don't particularly need with well-structured code)

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep Unless you've got a language that handles recursion gracefully (like Lisp) don't use it unless you really have to. Lots of professors like to make their students use recursion in courses, but in the real world it's rarely useful.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that valuable information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want to print a bunch of random ints:

```
function resc_int($recursions, callable $func, $args = array()) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $recursions; $i++) {
        echo call_user_func_array($func, $args);
    }
}
// resc_int(100, "rand", array(0, 1));
```

Completely untested. Caveat Lector.

The way this works is that instead of using recursion (which will use more and more memory the more recursions you have, as you can't garbage collect something with active references or you will get a segmentation fault later in PHP if it tries to access it), it uses iteration.

There's two kinds of "looping" in a sense.

### Looping/Recursion.

Technically Recursion is a loop, as you continue recursing until you reach a stop condition (else you get an infinite loop, which is bad for fairly painful reasons). The loop construct in PHP is `while()`.

### Iteration

In pretty much every single case (unless you have a *really good reason*) this is always the better choice when you need something that loops. Iteration is, to put it simply, counting up or down to a target integer. This is the `for()` construct; and hence, also the `foreach()` construct, which uses the number of elements in an array as a target integer and then counts towards it, picking elements out of the array as it goes.

This is more memory efficient, and is remarkably easy to work with in PHP. It can also infinite loop, like while can (just give it an impossible condition to work towards), so watch out for that.

In short: have fun with the standard library (pretty much every function you regularly need is **somewhere** in there), and remember that recursion is your *last* option, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

```
function resc($times, $cbFtn, Array $cbFtnArgs = array()) {

    if ($times != 0) {
        print call_user_func_array($cbFtn, $cbFtnArgs);
        resc($times - 1, $cbFtn, $cbFtnArgs);
    }

}

resc(4, 'rand', array(0, 1));
```

Comment: Why would you default an argument to something that is not valid?